# AJAX result doesn't wait for query to finish

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So basically I have this pop-up form that has a preventDefault on the submit button to prevent it from submitting initially. I user jQuery to send the input to an AJAX function and want to show the user a message based on the result of that AJAX function.

However, the data that I get from the AJAX function is always the same. It's almost as if it skips the query and echo's the first result it can.

Here's the code.

**HTML**

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="login.php" id="login-nav">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="login_email" id="login_email" placeholder="Email" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="login_password" id="login_password" placeholder="Password" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="login_btn" value="Log In"></input>
  </div>
  <span id="login_msg"></span>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $("#login-nav").find("input[type='submit']").click(function(event) {
    $('#login_msg').html("<img src='../img/default.gif'>")
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    loginSubmit_OnClick();
    });
});

function loginSubmit_OnClick() {
  var email = $('#login_email').val();
  var password = $('#login_password').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "login.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {email: email, password: password},
    success: function(result){
          if (result == "success") {
            $('#login_msg').html("<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Logged in.</div>");
          }
          if (result == "failed") {
            $('#login_msg').html("<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Wrong password!</div>");
          }
        }
    })
};
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

$success = false;
$email = $_POST['login_email'];

$stmt = $db->prepare(...);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$user_id = $result[0];
$email = $result[1];
$password = $result[2];

if ($result) {
  if (password_verify($_POST['login_password'], $password)) {
    $success = true;
  }
}

if ($success) {
  echo "success";
}
else {
  echo "failed";
}
?>
```

It always returns "failed" and shows the message "Wrong Password!" even though I'm 100% sure it should return success (tested it without the AJAX to be sure).

Comment: You didn't loop the `fetch` so it only checks the first account... or does you query use the username/password? You seem to have removed the query..

Comment: The query uses the email from the input field.

Comment: If you output `$result` in the `failed` did it find the correct user?

Comment: Your ajax request is sending the variables "email" and "password," but your PHP code is looking for the variables "login_email" and "login_password" from POST. You need to change these variables to match.

Comment: ...and/or use error reporting while developing.

Comment: The thing is I tried the exact same thing with the jQuery script removed, I used action="login.php" and it works like a charm. As soon as I use AJAX to do the same thing it breaks. @Josep Beard I tried changing those variables but it still gives me the same outcome..

Comment: *I tried changing those variables*  Okay, that's guesswork. Don't guess.  There is a correct answer.  Echo out the data you received.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your AJAX request parameters has correct keys? It seems like they may differ.

**Try to use:**

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: $('#login-nav').serialize(),
    ...
};
```

**instead of**

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {email: email, password: password},
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In ajax you are posting `data: {email: email, password: password},` but in php you expect `$_POST['login_email']` and `$_POST['login_password']`. If you do `var_dump($_POST);` it should contain *email* and *password* instead of *login_email* and *login_password*.

You can also use Ghiyas answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43263398/7081773). It will simulate sending the post as if javascript hasn't prevented the default behavior. Therefore it will send your inputs in post as intended.